# Removing padding gutter from grid columns in Bootstrap 4 / Bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

How do you create a gutterless grid in bootstrap 4?

Is there an official API for removing the gutter or is it manual?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**Bootstrap5:**
Comes with [gutter utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/)

- all viewports `g-0` .. `g-5`
- responsive viewports `g-sm-0` .. `g-lg-5`
- horizontal/vertical `gy-0` .. `gx-5`

Example with zero-gutter width:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="p-3 border bg-light">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="p-3 border bg-light">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap4:**
Comes with `.no-gutters` out of the box.
source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/21211/files

**Bootstrap3:**

*Requires custom CSS.*

Stylesheet:

```
.row.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;

  & > [class^="col-"],
  & > [class*=" col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Then to use:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
</div>
```

It will:

- Remove margin from the row
- Remove padding from all columns directly beneath the row

Comment: In bootstrap-5 you can use these class (mx, px) to remove the margin and padding of the div.
<div class="container mx-0 my-0 px-0 py-0">

Answer (score 16):

You should use [built-in bootstrap4 spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) for customizing the spacing of elements, that's more convenient method .

Answer (score 12):

> Need an edge-to-edge design? Drop the parent `.container` or `.container-fluid`.

Still if you need to remove padding from `.row` and immediate child columns you have to add the class `.no-gutters` with the code from @Brian above to your own CSS file, actually it's Not 'right out of the box', check here for official details on the final Bootstrap 4 release: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters

Answer (score 3):

You can use this css code to get gutterless grid in bootstrap.

```
.no-gutter.row,
.no-gutter.container,
.no-gutter.container-fluid{
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.no-gutter>[class^="col-"]{
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mixin `make-col-ready` and set the gutter width to zero:

`@include make-col-ready(0);`